# trying to upload my drawing using file-storage-component in loopback4

Tags: loopback4

Im trying to upload my drawing using file-storage-component in loopback4, but for any reason he send my a bad request, please help.

```
async onSubmit2($event){

    const file5 = "file";
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.simbolForm.get('fileSource').value);
    const obj2 = {
      file5: file5,
      file : this.simbolForm.controls.file.value,
      name: this.simbolForm.controls.fileSource.value
    }

   const result = await this.simbolService.postFile(obj2).toPromise();
   console.log(formData)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

loopback-storage-component is not compatible nor are there plans to make it compatible with LoopBack 4. This is due to the difference in the framework architecture. There are, however, several recommended alternatives:

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/migration-not-planned.html#storage-component